# Storing additional information in Image in SQL LocalDB

Tags: c#, image, localdb

So I'm storing Images in a SQL-LocalDB by converting them to `byte[]`:

```
private byte[] imageToByteArray(Image img)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

After a select I reconvert them back to images and display them:

```
private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArray)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
     Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return img;
}
```

But now I need to do additional checks with said images. So I thought ok, I'm gonna store some additional information in the `Tag` property of the images before saving them to the DB. After reconverting them back to images though, the information I stored in the `Tag` property is gone.
What I want to store additionally to the images is their respective index they had in the `ImageList` where I got them from so I can select and display them again.

Is there any way for me to achieve this without adding an additional column for the index in my DB?

Comment: Have you ever been thinking of storing the "images" in the db just as a path? So it just holds a reference where to find that image. So you wont end up storing it twice and you have access to all its meta data since you got it stored on your server?

Comment: Yes, I have. There's a number of reasons why I'm storing it as said in my question above. If it's possible to achieve what is asked for in my question, that is.

Comment: Why dont you add Field in your dB that hold that additional Information. Like index_indexlist and probably addiotional info about the insert itself (to Identity all Images that appear to be Part of a specific insert/imagelist) and then use a Query to get all Images in this specific imagelist ordered by their Index

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to avoid - hence I put "without adding an additiional column" in my question.

Comment: But that does not make sense. Lets have a thought - if it works. You add this tag, convert it to binary data. Save it. Now you have a huge app, and you want to request a particular imagelist (or all the images uploaded within this list). Now you have to select all images (or the binary data of them) convert them back, check for the tag. That means you have loop through every row in that db table to verify that you got ALL images with that specific tag. Even though you would like to make it happen, it doesnt make sense. Otherwise you could easily query and analyze..

Comment: There is no need for me to analyze the data. My select is based on different data also stored along the image - meaning when I get the image, i need an additional index for that image used for display. There is no analyzing or validation based on the image whats so ever. And for that reason it would be more convenient to store it within that image instead of adding an additional column.

Comment: not really since an additional column has no negative effect, is the easiest and fastest way and makes live much easier.

Comment: So the answer is no, there's no way to do what I intended to do, I guess.